# SQL Server could not convert data value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to import data from SQL Server to mysql using OPENQUERY with a linked server.

I have imported couple of tables but I am having an issue with a table that has a long varchar field.

everytime i run this query I get the following

```
Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Serv1" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]" because of column "Notes". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.
```

the column Notes is of the type varchar(8000) in SQL servr and also varchar(8000) in MySQL.

What is the issue? why it is giving me this error? not I have tried to case Notes to varchar(8000) first but that did not work.

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (Serv1, 'SELECT 
id,
i3_identity,
mid,
Notes,
Comments,
result_code,
Disposition,
completed_on,
calltype
FROM finaltesting.activities') 
  SELECT
  CAST(ID AS int) AS id,
  CAST(identity AS int) AS identity,
  CAST(merchantAccount AS varchar(255)) AS mid,
  Notes,
  CAST(Comments AS varchar(8000)) AS Comments,
  CAST(FinishCode AS varchar(255)) AS result_code,
  CAST(Disposition AS varchar(255)) AS Disposition,
  CAST(callDate AS datetime) AS completed_on,
  CAST(CallType AS varchar(255)) AS calltype
FROM activities
```

Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.

Comment: Maybe it's silly, but have you tried to `Creeate table` from that `select` ?

Comment: on the SQL Server side or in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by changes the column type in MySQL from varchar(8000) to Text. I am using MySQL 5.6.12. It is probably column type issue when converting form SQL Server to MySQL Server.

Thanks